# How to map array values to arrays inside an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, data-structures

I have an object which is as follows:

```
const data = [
  {name: 'Week 1', owner: 0, others: 4, amt: 4},
  {name: 'Week 2', owner: 0, others: 7, amt: 7},
  {name: 'Week 3', owner: 0, others: 10, amt: 10},
  {name: 'Week 4', owner: 0, others: 12, amt: 12},
  {name: 'Week 5', owner: 0, others: 3, amt: 3},
  {name: 'Week 6', owner: 0, others: 0, amt: 0},
  {name: 'Week 7', owner: 0, others: 9, amt: 9},
];
```

I have two arrays namely:

```
var arrayOwner = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var arrayOthers = [2,4,3,6,3,8,9];
```

The problem is that I have to take the first value of each array (`arrayOwner` and `arrayOthers`) and then update the first object inside the data array.

For example, for week 1, 0 from `arrayOwner` and 2 from `arrayOthers` would be taken and then updated in the first object of the data array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Mapping `data`

You can simply map with the [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method your array `data` and update two of object's value: `owner` and `others`.

> The [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.
>
> - [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The callback provided to `.map` can take multiple arguments: here we will use:

- currentValue: `e`
- index: `i`

Here's the code that will do the mapping:

```
const res = data.map((e,i) => {
  e.owner = arrayOwner[i];
  e.others = arrayOthers[i];
  return e
})
```

Full code:

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Week 1', owner: 0, others: 4, amt: 4},
  {name: 'Week 2', owner: 0, others: 7, amt: 7},
  {name: 'Week 3', owner: 0, others: 10, amt: 10},
  {name: 'Week 4', owner: 0, others: 12, amt: 12},
  {name: 'Week 5', owner: 0, others: 3, amt: 3},
  {name: 'Week 6', owner: 0, others: 0, amt: 0},
  {name: 'Week 7', owner: 0, others: 9, amt: 9},
];

const arrayOwner = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
const arrayOthers = [2,4,3,6,3,8,9];

const res = data.map((e,i) => {
  e.owner = arrayOwner[i];
  e.others = arrayOthers[i];
  return e;
})

console.log(res)
```

---

### Using a loop

You can actually modify `data` without having to define a separate array to get the modified array. We'll use [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach), the given callback will be the same as previously:

```
data.forEach((e,i) => {
  e.owner = arrayOwner[i];
  e.others = arrayOthers[i];
  return e;
});
```

Here `data` needs to be modifiable, don't define `data` with `const`. Use `var` or `let` instead.

```js
let data = [
  {name: 'Week 1', owner: 0, others: 4, amt: 4},
  {name: 'Week 2', owner: 0, others: 7, amt: 7},
  {name: 'Week 3', owner: 0, others: 10, amt: 10},
  {name: 'Week 4', owner: 0, others: 12, amt: 12},
  {name: 'Week 5', owner: 0, others: 3, amt: 3},
  {name: 'Week 6', owner: 0, others: 0, amt: 0},
  {name: 'Week 7', owner: 0, others: 9, amt: 9},
];

const arrayOwner = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
const arrayOthers = [2,4,3,6,3,8,9];

data.forEach((e,i) => {
  e.owner = arrayOwner[i];
  e.others = arrayOthers[i];
  return e;
});

console.log(data);
```

---

### Side note on data structure

If you would like a shorter version, you could set a different data structure for `arrayOwners` and `arrayOthers`. Maybe have them in the same array, instead of:

```
[arrayOwners[0], arrayOwners[1], ...]
```

and

```
[arrayOthers[0], arrayOthers[1], ...]
```

have:

```
[ [arrayOwners[0], arrayOthers[0]], [arrayOwners[1], arrayOthers[1]], ... ]
```

So then you would map it like so:

```
const res = data.map((e,i) => {
  [ e.owner, e.others ] = arrayMods[i]
  return e;
})
```

Above I'm using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to set `e.owner` to `arrayMods[i][0]` and `e.others` to `arrayMods[i][1]`. Which is more convenient.

```js
const data = [
  {name: 'Week 1', owner: 0, others: 4, amt: 4},
  {name: 'Week 2', owner: 0, others: 7, amt: 7},
  {name: 'Week 3', owner: 0, others: 10, amt: 10},
  {name: 'Week 4', owner: 0, others: 12, amt: 12},
  {name: 'Week 5', owner: 0, others: 3, amt: 3},
  {name: 'Week 6', owner: 0, others: 0, amt: 0},
  {name: 'Week 7', owner: 0, others: 9, amt: 9},
];

const arrayMods = [[0,2],[0,4],[0,3],[0,6],[0,3],[0,8],[0,0]];

const res = data.map((e,i) => {
  [ e.owner, e.others ] = arrayMods[i]
  return e;
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with:

```
data.forEach((item, key) => {
  item.owner = arrayOwner[key];
  item.others = arrayOthers[key];
});
```

Or without modifying the `data` object directly:

```
const newData = data.map((item, key) => ({
  ...item,
  owner: arrayOwner[key],
  others: arrayOthers[key],
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to update object with value from  `arrayOwner`& `arrayOthers`

```
 data.map((obj, key) => {
  data.owner = arrayOwner[key] ; // update current object with value from
  data.other = arrayOthers[key] ; //arrayOwner and arrayOthers
  return data;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a helper object and an array for the keys and loop while repecting the index for update.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: 'Week 1', owner: 0, others: 4, amt: 4 }, { name: 'Week 2', owner: 0, others: 7, amt: 7 }, { name: 'Week 3', owner: 0, others: 10, amt: 10 }, { name: 'Week 4', owner: 0, others: 12, amt: 12 }, { name: 'Week 5', owner: 0, others: 3, amt: 3 }, { name: 'Week 6', owner: 0, others: 0, amt: 0 }, { name: 'Week 7', owner: 0, others: 9, amt: 9 }],
    arrayOwner = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    arrayOthers = [2, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8, 9],
    update = { owner: arrayOwner, others: arrayOthers };

data.forEach((o, i) => ['owner', 'others'].forEach(k => o[k] = update[k][i]));
    
console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```